# Designing mobile apps for 360x640 screen sizes

Tags: android, ios

this is kind of a general question.

I'm working on an app and am getting a lot of overrun errors when I test it on a smaller phone.

Couple questions:

1. Is it possible to exclude the app from being available on smaller screen sizes (360x640) in the app and play store?
2. If it is possible.. is it worth the time to write the code for smaller phones?

Thanks

Comment: For  iOS you should ensure that your app runs on devices based on the minimum iOS level you target; so if you are targeting iOS 13 and later, that means supporting the iPhone 6s and iPhone SE. iOS 12 means you need to support the 5S. You cannot exclude specific device sizes in the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to exclude the app from being available on smaller screen sizes (360x640) in the app and play store?**

Yes for Android, Here is a link that shows you how to do it: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution#RestrictAppSizeDensity

No for iOS, but you do have the ability to restrict based on OS version and other hardware-based capabilities, these settings are accessible when you select the target and in the General panel, you can find the OS version in deployment info plus there are other options in build settings that you can play around with.

**If it is possible.. is it worth the time to write the code for smaller phones?**

It really depends on your target audience, look at your app stats and determine if you should or shouldn't support them.

Comment: Your answer - more so, your link - does it apply to iOS? It doesn't look it. So how is this an answer?

Comment: @dfd Well, the question asks about both app and play store, so this should answer at least half of it.

Comment: Sure, agreed. More - the question should not ask about both. At least you should be *specific* that all you are answering is for Android, not iOS. (For the record, a2+ year old answer of mine received a comment that it's a deprecated framework in iOS yesterday. I edited my answer to reflect that.)

Comment: This was my bad, I completely ignored the app store part.